# Make a division with a top triangle form and shadow

Tags: html, css

I need to make with html and css the same look of the image as shown below:

[image: triangle top with shadow and border gradient color]

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It is a place to ask questions after you have made reasonable efforts to do it yourself. This looks like you are just asking for someone to do it for you

Comment: that's the best i could find https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Comment: did u try something with the code?? or just asking to implement your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to something like this:

```css
#trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 60px solid red;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 320px;
}

#triangle-up {
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-left: 160px solid transparent;
  border-right: 160px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-up"></div>
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help  , but this will only give me a single triangle  but i don't want that i need the full division with the shape of a triangle on top with the border gradient and the red shadow

Comment: that's great thank you i still need to work with the shadow and gradient color to get the correct display